# How to read file unknow with encode and write to csv

Tags: c#, vb.net

Have any ideas or suggestions for me that can handle the problem of reading a file unknows convert to the csv file

[file example](https://gofile.io/?c=Fw5ahi)

Comment: The file is some sort of binary format.  Without the specification it is difficult to read.  Any idea where data came from?

Comment: thanks for reading jdweng .First this is file export from machine AnritsuRecording.But I have no way of reading this file

Comment: Perhaps you need to identify the file format first. Maybe they use their own proprietary format. Are you able to get the file format specification for `.ARD` files?

Comment: The file has a lot of white space so my guess is it contains a list of structures that has been serialized.

Answer (score 0):

The data is exported in standard format as csv file.
Can read and write as csv file so based on code is not ?

[export file csv](https://gofile.io/?c=xsRpPL)